# Ruby Regex: Match Until First Occurance of Character

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a file with lines that vary in their format, but the basic idea is like this:

```
- A block of text #tag @due(2014-04-20) @done(2014-04-22)
```

For example:

```
- Email John Doe #email @due(2014-04-20) @done(2014-04-22)
```

The issue is the #tag and the @due date do not appear in every entry, so some are just like:

```
- Email John Doe @done(2014-04-22)
```

I'm trying to write a Ruby Regex that finds the item between the "- " and the first occurrence of EITHER a hashtag or a @done/@due tag.

I have been trying to use groups and look ahead, but I can't seem to get it right when there are multiple instances of what I am looking ahead for. Using my second example string, this Regex:

```
/-\s(.*)(?=[#|@])/
```

Yields this result for (.*):

```
Email John Doe #email @due(2014-04-22)
```

Is there any way I can get this right? Thanks!

Comment: You're missing the `?` to make it a non greedy match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the `?` quantifier to make it a non greedy match. And I would remove  `|` from inside of your character class because it's trying to match a single character in the list (`#|@`) literally.

```
/-\s(.*?)(?=[#@])/
```

See [`Demo`](http://regex101.com/r/gF2hZ2)

You really don't need a **Positive Lookahead** here either, just match up until those characters and print the result from your capturing group.

```
/-\s(.*?)[#@]/
```

You could also use negation in this case.

```
/-\s([^#@]*)/
```

Comment: Cool. Just to follow-up, with or without the pipe yielded the same results. It was my understanding the pipe was like "or." Is that correct?

Comment: Outside of character class, `(?=#|@)`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
str = "- Email John Doe #email @due(2014-04-20) @done(2014-04-22)"
str[/-(.*?)#|@due|@done/,1]
  #=> " Email John Doe "
```

`(.*?)` is a capture group, with `?` making `.*` non-greedy.  The result of the capture is retrieved by the `,1` at the end.

Credit to @hwnd for noticing the need to make `.*` non-greedy shortly before I posted, though I did not see the comment until later.